# Opencv identify difference between similar object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am working on a project to figure out the difference between two objects and tag them with the proper model code.

I need help with a suggestion on how can we tackle such problem with image processing using OpenCV, following are the images

Till now I tried calculating black pixel difference between two images after doing binary threshold and also calculated a number of holes present on the gasket.

I also tried using feature points but it didn't worked well

what else can be done to improve the detection?

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Why does number of holes not distinguish these two shapes?

Comment: It does, but I have like 100's of such objects with varying shapes and holes. It may happen that any two of such object may have the same number of holes but different shape.

Comment: Well, what else is meaningful? Diameter, thickness, location of holes, ... Take any two shapes you can’t distinguish, and find a new concept that you would use to distinguish them, then add that as a feature to your set.

Comment: Actually, this is gaskets, I can't think of diameter as a feature to consider from my point of view Cris. Since this gaskets come in irregular shapes too.

Thank you for the tip, I'll try to figure out what else I can consider as feature by comparing two similar looking gaskets :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The holes are excellent features that can be robustly detected by blob analysis.

In the first place, locate the large circle and determine its center and radius. The radius might be a first discriminant feature.

Next, establish the configuration of the screw holes around the center. You can use the distance to the center, the number of holes and the angles they define around the center.

If this is still not enough, you can register the gaskets and compare them to the models by matching the screw holes, adjusting the rotation, then comparing pixel-wise with a similarity measure such as SAD or SSD.